# How to prevent notification bar from updating old notifications?

Tags: android, notifications, progress-bar, android-notifications, android-progressbar

I have an app that downloads file from a server, I have a list of file that a user can download.

The user press download 1 and starts downloading a files, if the user press download 2 once download 1 is complete it starts downloading the second download third and......

My problem is that when the program is done with one download it updated the notification bar  to download finished and also send in "intent" so when the user taps on the notification it send the id of the download,
the problem is, if i download more that one file all the intent share the same id....

Ex:
I click donwlod 1 --- the id for this download is 123

if this is the only file Im downloading is fine.

but if click download 2 --- the id for this download is 4321

when download 2 is done, on my top bar i have to notification one for download 1 and another one for download 2
and both notification have the same id in the intent "4321"

```
private boolean saveFile(ResponseBody body, String fileName, String id) {
        final int final_id = Integer.parseInt(id);
        Intent activityIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, activityIntent, 0);
        final NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_2_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_cloud_minload_black_24dp)
                .setContentTitle("Download")
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                .setContentText("Downloading......")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent);

        notificationManager.notify(final_id, notification.build());
        try {
            File futureStudioIconFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_minLOADS), fileName);

            InputStream inputStream = null;
            OutputStream outputStream = null;

            try {
                byte[] fileReader = new byte[4096];
                long fileS = body.contentLength();
                long fileDonwloaded = 0;

                inputStream = body.byteStream();
                outputStream = new FileOutputStream(futureStudioIconFile);

                while (true) {
                    int read = inputStream.read(fileReader);

                    if (read == -1) {
                        break;
                    } 
                    outputStream.write(fileReader, 0, read);

                    fileDonwloaded += read;

                    Long fileSD = fileDonwloaded;
                    Long fileS     = fileS;
                    int min = fileSD.intValue();
                    int max  = fileS.intValue();
                    int max2 = max - 1000000;
                    if( max2 > min) { 
                        notification.setProgress(max, min, false);
                        notificationManager.notify(final_id, notification.build());
                    } else {  
                        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        String id_d = Integer.toString(final_id);
                        notificationIntent.putExtra("ID" , id_d);
                        notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                        PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),0,notificationIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                        notification.setContentText("Downnload Finished");
                        notification.setProgress(0, 0, false);
                        notification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_cloud_done_black_24dp);
                        notification.setOngoing(false);
                        notification.setAutoCancel(true);
                        notification.setContentIntent(pendingNotificationIntent);
                        notificationManager.notify(final_id, notification.build());
                    }
                }
                return true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return false;
            } finally {
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    inputStream.close();
                }

                if (outputStream != null) {
                    outputStream.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        } 
    }
```